# select query in foxpro

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm trying this

```
col= thisform.combo4.DisplayValue+SUBSTR(thisform.combo3.DisplayValue,1,3)
SELECT col as a1 FROM doc WHERE com=thisform.combo1.DisplayValue INTO CURSOR c1
thisform.text30.Value=c1.a1
```

The variable col represent the name of column in the dbf
It results the name of the column not the value stored in that column

Answer (score 4):

```
col= thisform.combo4.DisplayValue+SUBSTR(thisform.combo3.DisplayValue,1,3)

* here I assume col is a correct string that represents an existing column


SELECT &col as a1 FROM doc ;
  WHERE com=thisform.combo1.DisplayValue ;
  INTO CURSOR c1 ;
  nofilter
thisform.text30.Value=c1.a1
```

IOW to be able to use a string in a Select for a column name, you need to use & (macro substition) operator.

Comment: Alan, saying "you need to use" you are right evaluate() is an option. I should have said "you should use". IMHO in an SQL select & is the way to go and it is probably one of the 1 or 2 places where & has a place to use (rest doesn't need & nor & should be used in other places, but we know many VFP users abuse it :)

Comment: It gives me an error: subscript is outside defined range

Comment: @BONIETTE,  create a var such as "dv = thisform.combo1.displayValue" and use THAT in the where clause.  VFP will use the . implying a table or alias . column name.  Since you have multiple dot notations, I have known VFP to get confused with that.  Try putting into a var, and you lose the issue of extra dot reference.

Comment: @BONIETTE, the error is not within this syntax. We don't know what does really "col" resolve to. If it is a valid column name then you wouldn't have an error but appearanly it is not.

Comment: @DRapp, VFP doesn't have such a "confusion", and can clearly interpret thisform.combo1.displayvalue. What you are saying is only a matter in update queries.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, that must have been where I remembered it but for preventing, applied the same across the board when dealing with any SQL.